# Debugging a Segmentation Fault

Tags: embedded, dynamic-linking, application, crash

I have an application that runs on an embedded Linux device that I am expanding with new features. The new features require GLib so, I am dynamically linking the required libraries to the application.

When I do this and run the application on the device, I get a segmentation fault. This occurs when I dynamically link the new libraries. GDB's backtrace shows that the fault occurs in another custom dynamically linked library. Unfortunately I only get a partial trace with the following message:

> Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC

Note that I am only linking another shared library and not adding any new code. If I linked the custom library statically the crash goes away. I suspect a memory corruption is happening somewhere else and the conditions (i.e. memory mapping) are just right when the custom library is dynamically linked so that the segmentation occurs.

Anyone know of any good tools and techniques I can use to debug further?

Comment: Are you compiling the custom libraries with debug symbols enabled?

Comment: @Faheem: Yes, everything is built with debug symbols

Comment: could you post the whole backtrace?

Comment: In addition to Faheem's question.  Is there a limit on the size of the coredump?

Comment: @Karlson: Unlimited. Also, optimizations are disabled. The back trace itself is not very useful. It only contains three stack frames from a custom library and not variables are available.

Comment: Make sure you're not using `-fomit-frame-pointer` when compiling. Its also quite possible you have a buffer overflow on the stack, which is corrupting the backtrace.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a discussion on similar subject on [Gmane](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gdb.devel/31422) and [Gentoo](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-779966.html) forums, so the answer may be found there.

In addition I would suggest starting with looking that your program at run time will load the right libraries so try `ldd` the dynamically linked file to see that you are actually running against right versions and then run the program through [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) because it's entirely possible that you are addressing memory you shouldn't and `valgrind` will be able to show that to you.